# string replace single quote to double quote in C#

Tags: c#, string, replace

How can I replace a single quote (') with a double quote (") in a string in C#?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to use the correct escape sequence for the quotes symbol, you can find more information about escape sequencies [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx).

```
String stringWithSingleQuotes= "src='http://...';";
String withDoubleQuotes = stringWithSingleQuotes.Replace("'","\"");
```

Answer (score 8):

```
var abc = "hello the're";
abc = abc.Replace("'","\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string str;
str=strtext.Replace('"','\'');
```

Comment: are we replacing " with ' with your code? I think it should be opposite.