# replace double quote with double double quote

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace

How can I perform this?

Current String:

```
string json = @"[{"data":{"JobID":"1",,"Amount":"6500","Description":"a"}}]";
```

Goal:

```
string json = @"[{""data"":{""JobID"":""1"",,""Amount"":""6500"",""Description"":""a""}}]";
```

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189269/string-replace-single-quote-to-double-quote-in-c-sharp?rq=1

Comment: Can you clarify? the first "string" isn't valid C# at all... the second one is... and the "how" is simply what you've already done: write valid C#

Comment: I think we've all underestimated the complexity of the question. I've got Martin Fowler's email address and I'm hoping he'll be joining the thread imminently.

Comment: @Marc: The first string I got as a json response. It is like this actually.
"\"[{\\\"fieldValuePair\\\":{\\\"JobID\\\":\\\"1\\\",\\\"BillGenerationDate\\\":\\\"4/18/2013 5:45:22 PM\\\",\\\"BillID\\\":\\\"115546\\\",\\\"BillNo\\\":\\\"115546\\\",\\\"CustomerID\\\":\\\"6726332\\\",\\\"PayStatus\\\":\\\"0\\\",\\\"PaymentRequiredStatus\\\":\\\"True\\\",\\\"DueType\\\":\\\"1\\\",\\\"Duedate\\\":\\\"2013-04-30\\\",\\\"ProductName\\\":\\\"PSE&G Gas Bill\\\",\\\"Amount\\\":\\\"400\\\",\\\"Description\\\":\\\"PSEG Bill Apr Week 4\\\"}}]\""

Comment: @BijoyKJose yes, but I think you're simply tripping over the escaping; the JSON that you get *in a `string` instance* is not the same representation as that same JSON written as a C# literal - because the C# literal has to have escaping to know where the literal starts/ends.

Comment: @BijoyKJose that example seems to show a *different* escaping - again, I think all we're talking about here is escaping, not actually "replacing" any values. Your best bet would be to show that unescaped somewhere... i.e. the actual json without any additional escaping. You can do that by pasting it into your post as a code-block (indent 4 spaces, or ctrl+k)

Answer (score 3):

Simply try `Replace("\"", "\"\"")`

```
string json = "[{\"data\":{\"JobID\":\"1\",,\"Amount\":\"6500\",\"Description\":\"a\"}}]";

string result = json.Replace("\"", "\"\"");
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The question may not be a 'replace " with ""' one - on second read, it looks like the question is actual one of C# verbatim string literals...

Comment: @MarcGravell maybe. Anyway I tried to provide an answer in which fits the input and output that is stated in the Q.

Comment: @Hossein the input is invalid to start with...

Comment: @MarcGravell yes and I also provide the correct one for him.

Comment: @Hossein: Tried out this. But didnt change

Comment: @BijoyKJose it is working, if you are using desktop app use `MessageBox.Show(result)` to see the result.

Comment: re your recent edit: that is the *wrong* string; note the fact that the "desired output" is a verbatim string literal; that means that any `""` you see are actually `"` - so the desired output is `[{"data":{"JobID":"1"...` - single-quotes, not double-quotes

Comment: @MarcGravell if the desired output is what you are saying, so what the `double double quote` means?

Comment: @BijoyKJose if the output shown in my answer is not what you are looking for tell me so I can delete this post.

Answer (score 2):

The `@"..."` syntax in C# is a verbatim string literal; that means that instead of using escaping like `\n`, `\"` etc, the compiler handles all characters directly, except for `"` which must be represented by `""`. Because of this, the following line is not valid C#:

```
string json = @"[{"data":{"JobID":"1",,"Amount":"6500","Description":"a"}}]";
```

That violates the escaping rules for C# verbatim string literals. The correct C# is ***what you already have***:

```
string json = @"[{""data"":{""JobID"":""1"",,""Amount"":""6500"",""Description"":""a""}}]";
```

Since the first line is not valid *in any way*, it is meaningless to ask how to convert between them, other than to say: write valid C#.

However, the second string still represents the *json* data:

```
[{"data":{"JobID":"1",,"Amount":"6500","Description":"a"}}]
```

The `""` in the C# ***do not exist***; they are just the escaping - you need to read them as `"`.

Comment: in fact, the questions comes from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216701/json-deserialization-issue-with-xamarin-android/16216840#comment23218559_16216840 I think you can see my deleted answer and can explain it to the OP. I couldn't